# block in bash so that no more than 5 child processes are running at a time?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, wait

Is there a way to block in bash, something like this:

```
function do_work {

   wait -c 5 ### wait until 5 or fewer cp's are running
   now do whatever else you wanted

}
```

Comment: Might GNU `parallel` let you manage the number of running children?

Comment: not sure if it will, since I am dynamically adding more jobs basically...need some sort of queue